# How can I achieve shadows only at the corners of a rectangle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows

I'm looking to recreate this effect in Photoshop by giving a shadow only to the corners of the rectangle (in this case a sticky note):

[image: shadow example]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either use a normal drop shadow for the outer irregular one (a short distance with a larger size will let you see the borders all around the shape), which will give you something like this:

[image]

Or manually add one for the bottom corners using shapes, transformations and blur:

[image]

To recreate it just:

- Duplicate the shape in the back, and use the `Warp` tool to lower the bottom corners
- Apply a `Gaussian blur` to the shadow shape